# PHP и MySql так и должно быть?

Tags: php, mysql

Вообщем ковырявшись с кодом php который выводит из базы данных информацию прим. ниже заметил такую вешь все дублируется. Это так и должно быть или у меня, что то не так?

Простой код:

```
$test = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `cms_plugins`");
```

$res = mysql_fetch_array($test);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($res);
echo "</pre>";

Выводит вот такое:

```
Array
```

(
    [0] => 1
    [id] => 1
    [1] => sdhc7sbd7
    [plugin_id] => sdhc7sbd7
    [2] => youtube frames enable
    [title] => youtube frames enable
    [3] => tube_admin.php
    [link] => tube_admin.php
    [4] => settings.php
    [settings] => settings.php
    [5] => This plugin is convert http:// youtube or dailymotion to the frame
    [description] => This plugin is convert http:// youtube or dailymotion to the frame
    [6] => 1
    [type] => 1
    [7] => 1
    [active] => 1
)

Сервер denwer/windows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

да, что бы этого избежать можно использовать ключ

```
mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)
или 
mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)
```

И еще момент, пора уже переходить на пдо, а то скоро это все уже поудаляют:

http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-fetch-array.php

Comment: интересно. А не подскажешь видео, туториалы насчет PDO я просто новенький в PHP

Comment: http://www.rutor.org/torrent/154641/specialist-videokursy-po-internet-tehnologijam-web-html-css-php-javascript-ajax-i-dr-2010-2011-pc

Вот полный набор, не в стиле Попова, все грамотно. 

Гляньте еще в сторону Yii

Comment: Вопрос из той же серии вытаскиваю из базы масивы их два а выходит три (Один пустой)как так? 
код: 

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `cms_plugins`);  
while($postrow[] = mysql_fetch_assoc($result));


https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/60951854/result.PNG  

Вообщем как вывести из базы все таблицы в массив без while потому что я думаю дело в while.

Comment: Так и должно быть, я тоже на такое натыкался в свое время. 
Точно не помню с чем это связанно, но вот решение:

 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cms_plugins);

 while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
  $results[] = $row;
 }

 echo '<pre>';
 print_r($results);
 echo '</pre>';

Comment: Спасибо ты решил мою задачку как нужно!!!!

Comment: проклятье, я кавычку пропустил в 1 строке.